# On click does not trigger if clicking on a child element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can trigger an action or event using `on click` if I'm clicking on a child element. Apparently the button works if I tried clicking on the parent, but if I tried clicking on the text within which is the child element. The action or event does not trigger.

Here is what the component looks like. Clicking on space around it which is the parent, the event works. But if I tried clicking on the text it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is what the markup looks like.

```
    <div class="modal">
     <div class="view-types -bordered">
         <div class="view-type">
             <div class="view-switch-list">List</div>
         </div>
         <div class="view-type">
             <div class="view-switch-map">Map</div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
'use strict';

(function($) {

    var viewSwitch = {

        init : function() {

            this.$viewTab = $('.modal .view-types .view-type');
            this.$viewLayout = $('.modal .view-layout');

            this.select(1);
            this.$viewTab.on('click', this._onTabClick.bind(this));
        },

        select: function(i) {
            this._reset();
            $(this.$viewTab[i]).children('div').addClass('-active');
            $(this.$viewLayout[i]).addClass('-active');
        },

        _onTabClick: function(e) {
            let index = $(e.target).index();
            this.select(index);

        },

        _reset: function() {
            this.$viewTab.children('div').removeClass('-active');
            this.$viewLayout.removeClass('-active');
        },
    }

    $(window).on('load', function() {
            viewSwitch.init();
    })


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You forgot to include the parent element with class modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blieve this is why it fails to work: when user clicks the text, `e.target` now refers to the text, not the parent wrapper. Try change `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` and see if it works?

edit: reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Properties

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work on mine (after adding the .modal parent); even if I click the text element inside, the `alert("Hello World")` is still triggered.

Do try the snippet, thanks.

```js
'use strict';

(function($) {

  var viewSwitch = {

    init: function() {

      this.$viewTab = $('.modal .view-types .view-type');
      this.$viewLayout = $('.modal .view-layout');

      this.select(1);
      this.$viewTab.on('click', this._onTabClick.bind(this));
    },

    select: function(i) {
      this._reset();
      $(this.$viewTab[i]).children('div').addClass('-active');
      $(this.$viewLayout[i]).addClass('-active');
    },

    _onTabClick: function(e) {
      alert("Hello World!");
      let index = $(e.target).index();
      this.select(index);

    },

    _reset: function() {
      this.$viewTab.children('div').removeClass('-active');
      this.$viewLayout.removeClass('-active');
    },
  }

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    viewSwitch.init();
  })


})(jQuery);
```

```css
.view-type {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="view-types -bordered">
    <div class="view-type">
      <div class="view-switch-list">List</div>
    </div>
    <div class="view-type">
      <div class="view-switch-map">Map</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```